# Table with hidden columns, when made visible have gap between them

Tags: javascript

I have a table with only single visible column. The other column headers are listen in a dropdown.
When a value is selected from a dropdown the column becomes visible.
But if two non-adjacent columns are selected and made visible they have gaps (of the columns that exist are between them and are hidden).
Can any one help me get rid of the gap in between the visible columns?
Thanks

**Code for TableTable in Velocity:**

```
<table id="table_datagrid" class="ma-calendar-table" >

      <thead>
        <tr>
         <th class="sorting calendar_th" style="word-wrap:break-word; white-space: pre;">Test</th>

           #foreach($col in $columns)
               #if($col != 'Test')
                  <th class="sorting calendar_th column_${velocityCount}" style="word-wrap:break-word; max-width:130px; white-space: normal; visibility: hidden;">$col</th>
               #end
           #end

        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
       #foreach($row in $result)
          <tr>
            <td class="metric_name"> $row.get('Test')<br>&nbsp; </td>

            #foreach($colm in $columns)
              #if($colm != 'Test')

                #if( !$row.get($colm) || $row.get($colm)=='')
                  #set($val = '')
                #else
                  #set($val = $row.get($colm))
                #end                  

                <td class="metric_value column_${velocityCount}" style=" max-width:130px; visibility: hidden;">$val</td>
                #set($val = '')
              #end
            #end

          </tr>
        #end              
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
$('#status_sel').on("change", function() {

    var sel_wloads = $('#status_sel').select2("val");           
    for (var i = 0; i < sel_wloads.length; i++) {

        var name = 'column_'+sel_wloads[i];
        console.log(name);

        $('.'+name).each(function(){

            console.log($(this).text());
            $(this).css("visibility","visible");
        });
    }

});
```

},

Comment: Edit with some code please ;)

Comment: Well, w/o seeing *any* code, this is taking a wild stab at things, but do you have `cellspacing` or `cellpadding` set? Not forced to zero?  Using a library?  I have so many more questions, but you'd be super cool if you added some code. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"

i think it will help you. if you still get problem, please paste table with some dummy data, so it may be more clear

Comment: I am unable to share images.

Comment: So I have a table with hidden columns.. which get displayed after selection from a dropdown.. So Its kind of a filtering on Columns. But when I make them visible, the Columns have spaces due to the hidden columns between them. Its not related to cellspacing and cellpadding.